# How to manage dequeue cell with background operations

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, background, uicollectionviewcell

I have a generic question about UITableViewCell and UICollectionviewCell.

I need to download a file for every cell, so i create a background operation when i create a cell, but the user can scroll the tableview/collectionview so a cell can be recycled for other row.

I can interrupt the background operations inside the "prepareForreuse" methods but this is a bit annoying because if the operation is at 99% you need to restart download. So i decided to maintain the background process but i need a way to "recognize" that when the backgorund thread ends the cell isn't the same as when it started.

sorry if question are not very clear.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is the best approach, to link the background tasks with the cells and then handle the reuse.

You should create tasks when a cell is created and use the index path to identify which cell should handle the result of the task.

In this way, you won't kill any task and you can also check if your task is completed so you won't start again when the user scroll the table view.

Comment: hum...very nice and clean approach. Maybe i need to add more code, like a NSOperationQueue instead of a simple dispatch_async inside the UITableViewCell but in this way i can have full control of background process.

Comment: Like I said, I don't think it is a good approach to link cell reuse and background threads it will create lots and lots of problems when you will try to control the background threads. But this is your own decision. :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide details on how you perform your background operation and how you inform the cell of its completion? (code!)

Edit:

You could also use a singleton to manage all the background operations, assigning one unique identifier for each cell so that an operation is unique. You then proceed to check in cellForRowAtIndexPath: if there is an item with the cell identifier in your background manager, and you check its contents.
And yeah, the identifier can be the indexPath, as danypata said (other answer)